# Erroneous update of ArrayList records when a new record is added

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a table of tasks and manipulate its contents. I am tackling with a bug I don't understand, and be very thankful for help. I applogoze for the length of the question, but trying to bring as much details as possible.

The class **tasksRepository** stores the records, which are constructed in the class **taskDef**, as array list. The **setTask** () and **getTask** methods contains the add() and get() methods of the ArrayList class.

The **taskDef** object's parameters are created using local set methods. The following is an example to such method: If the delivered parameter differs from the stored value it will be stored value and the event will be added to the log record. In any case a success flag is retuned.

```
public static Boolean setProjectNumber(String projectNumberI)
{ // All the 
    if (projectNumberI != projectNumber)
    {
        projectNumber = projectNumberI;
        logAccumulator = logAccumulator + "; project number (" + projectNumberI + ")";
    }
    return true;
}

private static void setLog ()
{ // When all the parameters are set, the log parameter is updated with time tag
    String t = formatterFull.format(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime());
    log = log + "\n" + t + ": " + logAccumulator;       
}
```

The class **tasksTableProcessing** contains the tasks manipulation. The following contains the constructor. It was started in a simpler form, but during the investigation I changed it. The class **taskStatus** is ENUM that returns strings. The method **getLog** () simply returns the log field

```
public tasksTableProcessing () 
{ // constructor. Creates the tableRepository object with test records
    tasksRepository.clearDb ();

    taskDef task = null; 
    task = new taskDef ("P1000", "O1", taskStatus.started (), "1", "false", "false");
    tasksRepository.addTask (task);
    System.out.println("\nLog 0: \n" + tasksRepository.getTask(0).getLog());

    task = null;
    task = new taskDef ("P1000", "O1", taskStatus.started(), "2", "false", "true");
    tasksRepository.addTask (task);
    System.out.println("\nLog 1: \n" + tasksRepository.getTask(1).getLog());

    task = null;
    task = new taskDef ("P2000", "O2", "closed", "63", "true", "false");
    tasksRepository.addTask (task);
    System.out.println("\nLog 2: \n" + tasksRepository.getTask(2).getLog());

    task = null;
    task = new taskDef ("P2000", "O2", "closed", "64", "true", "true");
    tasksRepository.addTask (task);
    System.out.println("\nLog 3: \n" + tasksRepository.getTask(3).getLog());
}
```

The following is the log. It shows that when a new record is introduced, all the old records are updated.

> > Log 0:
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started)
> >
> > Log 1:
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started)
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started); task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true)
> >
> > Log 2:
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started)
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started); task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true)
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started); task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true); project number (P2000); task (Task 63); task ID (63); owner (O2); status (closed); critical path (true); delivery flag (false)
> >
> > Log 3:
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started)
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started); task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true)
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started); task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true); project number (P2000); task (Task 63); task ID (63); owner (O2); status (closed); critical path (true); delivery flag (false)
> >
> > 09/07/2012 10:21: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started); task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true); project number (P2000); task (Task 63); task ID (63); owner (O2); status (closed); critical path (true); delivery flag (false); task (Task 64); task ID (64); delivery flag (true)

Comment: Great background, but I don't sure I can see where is the problem.

Comment: Can you show the code of taskDef's constructor and tasksRepository.addTask (task)'s definition ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the method signatures, you store the members of your TaskDefs as static fields, rather than instance fields. A static field is a field of the class TaskDef itself, and not a field of a specific TaskDef instance.

Read the Java tutorial about [instance and class members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: Thank yo so much: removing the static declarations (that were added in the past due to some compilation problem) resolved the issue completely