# ArrayList members are modified when a record is added

Tags: java, arraylist

This is in continuation to a question I posted yesterday ( [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392179/erroneous-update-of-arraylist-records-when-a-new-record-is-added)), for its asnwer I am greatful - undoubtly it solved a barrier.

Following the advice I removed the **static** modifiers. This, indeed, solved the issue of accumulated changes to the records. However, when I returned from the simplified application, built for the issue debugging, to the original environment, I noticed that adding a record still cause modification of the previous records. I assume it is something wrong I am doing with the ArrayList.

I simplified the application by removing all **static**, **final** and **synchronized** modifiers (regardless of its relevance to the problem) and still have the problem.

I narrowed the issue to the **add** method brought below. The method is called by the constructor of the data repository with test records with incremental ID field and various values of other fields.

```
private ArrayList<taskDef> tasksTable = new ArrayList<taskDef>();

public void addTask (taskDef newRecord)
{ // Add  the record at the array's end
    Boolean f = tasksTable.add(newRecord);
    System.out.println( "\n>************** storing record (index " + (getTasksTableLength () - 1) + 
                        ")\tProject: " + tasksTable.get(getTasksTableLength () - 1).getProjectNumber() + 
                         "\tID: " + tasksTable.get(getTasksTableLength () - 1).getId() + 
                        "\ttable size: " + getTasksTableLength () + "\tsuccess: " + f + 
                        "\tLog: " + tasksTable.get(getTasksTableLength () - 1).getLog());
    if (getTasksTableLength () > 1)
        System.out.println( ">************** Previous record (index " + (getTasksTableLength () - 2) + "): " + 
                             "\tProject: " + tasksTable.get(getTasksTableLength () - 2).getProjectNumber() + 
                             "\tID: " + tasksTable.get(getTasksTableLength () - 2).getId() + 
                             "\tLog: " + tasksTable.get(getTasksTableLength () - 2).getLog());
}
```

In the log we can see that whenever a record is added the previous tasks are changed. The following printout shows only one previous record, but actually all previous records are being modified

```
>************** storing record (index 0)    Project: P1000  ID: 1   table size: 1   success: true   Log: 
11/07/2012 07:14:02: ; project number (P1000); task (Task 1); task ID (1); owner (O1); status (started)

>************** storing record (index 1)    Project: P1000  ID: 2   table size: 2   success: true   Log: 
11/07/2012 07:14:41: ; task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true)
>************** Previous record (index 0):  Project: P1000  ID: 1   Log: 
11/07/2012 07:14:41: ; task (Task 2); task ID (2); delivery flag (true)

>************** storing record (index 2)    Project: P1000  ID: 3   table size: 3   success: true   Log: 
11/07/2012 07:16:08: ; task (Task 3); task ID (3); owner (O2)
>************** Previous record (index 1):  Project: P1000  ID: 2   Log: 
11/07/2012 07:16:08: ; task (Task 3); task ID (3); owner (O2)
```

Comment: When you say you removed all "static" modifiers, did you do this for the taskDef class as well? 

Also, it's not a big deal, but it's standard java procedure to capitalize your class names (ie; TaskDef).

Comment: Can you please post the source of the Class 'taskDef'? Based upon that I think we can give you a valid answer! I believe that you have static  attached to Project variable!

Comment: Yes, I removed the **static** declarations from the **taskDef** class. I searched the classes for the **static** string. This class is built from a constructor, that calls for various setters. A typical setter looks like this:

Comment: Thanks: I searched the files with internal and external editors to find all the instances of the string "static", and foound some that slept from my yesterday's action. Issue is solved - thank you very much.